# having difficulties with encryption and decryption in oracle

Tags: encryption, plsql, oracle11g

My requirement is to encrypt varchar2 column and store that value again in that same column, and later again want to decrypt it and store actual value in same column .

I use `dbms_crypto` package but its encrypted value exceeds the length of the input column so I tried a compression function but did not achieve the result.

```
DECLARE
  lv_input VARCHAR2(20) := 'shrikant';
  lv_output VARCHAR2(200) ;
  lv_out VARCHAR2(20);
  lv_raw_again RAW(20) ;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_input||'lenth '||length(lv_input));
  lv_output := rawtohex(DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (lv_input), 4353,
      UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('zzzzzzzzz')));
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_output||'length  '||LENGTH(lv_output));

  lv_raw_again := hextoraw(lv_output);

  lv_out := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_crypto.Decrypt(src => lv_raw_again,
                typ => 4353,
                key => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('zzzzzzzzz') ));
   dbms_output.put_line(lv_raw_again||'length  '||LENGTH(lv_raw_again));                            
   dbms_output.put_line(lv_out||LENGTH(lv_out));                      
 END;
```

Here my input length is 8 and I want its encrypted result length also as 8 so I can store that value in that same field.

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance on formating but same i am expecting on the problem

Comment: Output Properly done encryption (with IV added) and encoding (rawtohex) will always be longer than original source.

Comment: @gusto2 Well, there is format preserving encryption (FPE) or, in the case of 8 byte values, blowfish or 3DES block encryption. However, I don't think this is present in most libs so the options may be limited. I don't know PLSQL though

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Indeed there is FPE, but he needs to dod that himself..

Comment: THis is a great question, but I'd like understand the use case a little more. You have col tabA.colE which you want to obfuscate/encrypt. I guess there would be a class of users/roles for which the column would appear encrypted, and another group who will see it decrypted. How will you control this? Will the decrypt group have access through a view in which a PLSQL function is call to do the decryption? Could you instead use Row Level Security views to hide/expose this column to particular groups of users instead without the need to do this FPE?

Comment: basically in first all data is visible because it get from flat file  but through a procedure it get encrypted and later when again it require for transacation it get back convrted in normal visible state so for encrypting we take one dummy table of main table in which all encrypted data get store and aginst which we update main table with encrypted data

Comment: You're looking for a two-way hash of some data but want to retain the VARCHAR2(20) format. How about having a 2nd table which stores a numeric sequence PK and the un-encrypted value, and in your main table you stored the key to this second table. You encryption routine would simply be to stored the value in the 2nd table, return the NEXTVAL for the sequence. Your decrypt would be to look up the value.Wrap appropriate security around the second table, and the stored procedure. If you cannot have this 2nd table, then to meet your requirement you need to write your own en/decrypt- not hackproof.